# Initialize Disk - Will It Wipe my data?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, clone, disk2vhd

I have four disks from a Buffalo Terrastation NAS which were setup in a RAID5 configuration. The terrastation apparently runs a linux based software RAID.

Unfortunately one disk has failed entirely, and I have a second disk which is working intermittently (it works then stops, then works then stops)

RAID5 arrays will allow one disk failure but not two so I'm in a bit of a predicament. I need to recover that second almost failed drive before it stops working entirely. Otherwise I've lost all my data - which I'd prefer not to do. :)

Rather than trying to get the entire RAID array back online (which takes hours due to a consistency check needing to run) I just want to try to clone the failing disk from another system. The trouble is that when I take the disk (or any disk out of the system and plug it into my windows system, windows see's the disk as uninitialized.

So I can't clone it with any of the windows tools. I'm not sure if its "safe" to initialize the disk in windows. Will that wipe the data or otherwise make it unreadible? If so, how can I get the drive online enough to clone it from windows?

Ideally I'd like to use disk2vhd to make a VHD of each drive. I'll then attempt to recreate the software RAID array with the VHDs without having to access the physical drives any more.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

IMO your best shot, since you have RAID 5 and still are able to access your data, is to make a backup first at another location (I know that indeed it could take some time, but it is required in order for your data to be safe. ) and after that replace the failed drive with a new one so the array could be rebuild. Once you're done with this you may consider replacing the other problematic HDD.

There is no sure way to say what exactly will happen if you plug the HDD in a PC, but most likely it will require you to reformat the hard disk in order to be recognized, which will wipe all the information stored on it.

Hope this helps and best of luck! :)